# NS Oscar II should I drain the boiler before storage?

Tags: espresso-machine, storage

I' have a Nuova Simonelli Oscar II machine for events. There is considerable time between those events and I was wondering if I should drain the boiler before storage.

The usual storage time is about 6 months or longer.

Or what are the possible issues that may raise from draining / not draining the boiler.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Oscar 1 has a brass plug that can be removed with a wrench. You can then pick the machine up and tip it over a drain. Some water might remain in the heat exchanger and tubes, but that will get almost all water out. I don't know whether the boiler design on the Oscar 2 is the same, but it wouldn't be surprising.

If there is any possibility of storage temperatures going below freezing, you must drain it. I would drain the machine regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The storage is in heated space - so that's covered.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, I don't know enough. I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. But you should be aware of nasty things growing in your water, like salmonella. At the cafe I worked at they left the machine on overnight to combat this. For your situation; I'm not sure. Maybe you're risking scale buildup, rust and general stale water. I'd definitely at least flush the boiler when you power it up again, no one likes the taste of stale water.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm quite sure that _Salmonella_ would not survive the proper heating of the boiler. Also the scale buildup is generally from the boiling of water, not the same water being in the same place. I'm more concerned about possible corrosion. Also any tips on how to quickly flush whole boiler on NS Oscar II?